# specific php session variables lost in Chrome only,

Tags: php, google-chrome, session

I lose some session variables in Chrome only
After reading every similar question and answer on this site, I have to note:
It is not a 404 / missing favicon issue
Also not a redirect issue. The session is started and closed properly.

I have a $_SESSION['customer'] and $_SESSION['order'] variable, for instance. 
As expected, $_SESSION['customer'] holds an object of customer data, $_SESSION['order'] holds an array of products.

When I add a product to the order, I need to look up any customer discounts for this specific product. Then it turns out in Chrome, the $_SESSION['customer'] variable is missing, and the sql query returns no discounts, since there is no customer number.

Let's give you some code to work with:

I am on the update order page, where I still have my customer and order variable.
I call this function with an ajax request to return a list of products:

```js
 public function live_search_product(){
 $this->load->model('orders', 'orders');
 $qry = $_GET['qry'];
 if (strlen($qry)>0) {
 $products = $this->orders_model->search_products($qry, false);
  if ($products){
   foreach ($products as $product){
    echo '<a href="?route=orders/orders/add_product&id='.$product['product_id'].'">'.$product['short_title'] . '</a><br>';
   }
  }
 }
 }
```

I select the product from the dropdown list, and end up in this function, where I suddenly have lost my $_SESSION['customer'] object and $_SESSION['order'] array. Please note that all my other session variables still exist.

```
public function add_product() {
    $this->load->model('orders', 'orders');
    $product = $this->orders_model->get_product_by_id($this->router->id);
    $discount = $this->discount->get_discount($product->id, $product->product_group_id, $_SESSION['customer']->id, $_SESSION['customer']->group_id );
      $_SESSION['order'][$this->router->id] = array('product' => $product ,
                                           'quantity' => 1,
                                           'rental' => 0,
                                           'bruto' => $product->price_ex,
                                           'discount' => $discount->discount_percentage,
                                           'netto' => ((100 - $discount->discount_percentage)/100) * $product->price_ex,
                                           'total' => ((100 - $discount->discount_percentage)/100) * $product->price_ex);       

    $this->calculate_order_totals();
}
```

In firefox and iexplorer and edge there is no problem, it works. 
I really hope you have any other suggestions.

**** EDIT ****
Every controller has an index function that is called automatically. route orders/orders will call orders/orders/index, and for instance route orders/orders/add_product, will call the function add_product in the orders controller (residing in the orders folder).

It turns out that in Chrome, somehow I get routed to the index function of this orders controller. Which is an overview orders function where I reset all order variables, to make sure nothing is left when I open a new order.
I have changed that, so this specific situation is solved.

However, can not understand why I get redirected to this function, when calling the add_product function directly.
Any ideas?

Comment: Could you try to dump the URI, as seen by the server, and check if it's what you expect? Maybe chrome is parsing your URI and dropping off some of the URL